# Why does the base pointer point to the top of the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention, att, stack-frame

In the "Programming from the ground up" book, I see the stack frame when calling function is somewhat like this

```
parameter 2    <- 12(%ebp)
parameter 1    <-  8(%ebp)
return address <-  4(%ebp)
ebp            <-   (%ebp)
local var 1    <- -4(%ebp)
local var 2    <- -8(%ebp) and (%esp)
```

It says that when the function return, it stores the return value to `%eax`, then it restore the `%ebp` and `%esp` to the position before the function was called, then the `ret` will pop whatever on top of the stack and point `%eip` to that address (which is supposed to be the return address). But when I see the code, I kinda suspect the line

```
movl %ebp, %esp # This
popl %ebp       # And this
ret
```

Why does it point the base pointer to the top of the stack? Isn't when `popl` is executed, only one local variable will be gone (because that's where `%esp` is pointing?)

Comment: This *is* the part that restores ESP and EBP (like `leave`), in a function that moved the stack pointer to make room for locals.  You know AT&T syntax is `op  src, dst` right?

Comment: Oh shoot I totally forgot that. Sorry, I get it now. Thank you.